# How to toggle text decorations

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

How do I toggle the line-through (`textDecoration`) on the list below when clicked?

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.textDecoration.toggle('line-through');
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>read a book</li>
  <li>play the guitar</li>
  <li>pay the bills :(</li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't work, but

```
e.target.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
```

adds the line-through where I want it, I just don't know how I can do this using the toggle function? I know I could this with If Else statements.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use `toggle()`? You're asking a bit of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle based on the current value of that style property.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    item.style.textDecoration = item.style.textDecoration === 
      'line-through' ? '': 'line-through';
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>read a book</li>
  <li>play the guitar</li>
  <li>pay the bills :(</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, toggle a class.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    item.classList.toggle('line-through');
  })
})
```

```css
.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>read a book</li>
  <li>play the guitar</li>
  <li>pay the bills :(</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I knew I could use toggle to change the class, I just thought their would be an easier method with just using the toggle method. Where can I get info on the first method? 

item.style.textDecoration = item.style.textDecoration === 
      'line-through' ? '': 'line-through';

Comment: @PrinceDev It's just the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Ah thanks, that's helpful. Why was item.style.textDecoration = item.style.textDecoration === necessary though? Would just item.style.textDecoration === work too?

Comment: @PrinceDev No, the order of operations is like this: `item.style.textDecoration = (item.style.textDecoration === 'line-through' ? '': 'line-through');`